# search lines of file for email address - returning whole line, with bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a file (sizes.txt)

```
daveclark@foo.com 0 23252 0
mikeclark@foo.com 0 45131 1
clark@foo.com 0 55235 0
joeclark@bar.net 33632 1
maryclark@bar.net 0 55523 0
clark@bar.net 0 99356 0
```

Now I have another file (users.txt)

```
clark@foo.com
clark@bar.net
```

What I want to do is find each line in sizes.txt for the specific email addresses in users.txt...using a loop, bash or one-liner in CentOS.  Here's the key point, I need to find lines that only contain clark@foo.com and then clark@bar.net - meaning this should be one line only for each.

The most simple way that comes to mind...

```
for i in `cat users.txt`; do grep $i sizes.txt; done
```

...but this does not work because processing the first line of users.txt will return the lines containing daveclark@foo.com, mikeclark@foo.com and clark@foo.com.  I explicitly want the line containing "clark@foo.com" (the third line of sizes.txt).  Processing second line of users.txt, will have the same problem (it will return maryclark@bar.net and clark@bar.net lines)  I know this has to be something totally simple that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the exact match with grep. In your case that would be the -w option.

So

> for i in `cat users.txt` do
>        grep -w "^$i" sizes.txt
>   done

should do the trick.

Cheers.

Comment: Appreciate it, but you kind of took the bait - this won't work. Add                        steve.clark@foo.com 0 32525  0 and                                             
mike-clark@foo.com 0 23235 0  to the top of the sizes.txt fie and watch what gets returned.  The -w switch does not work on grep for my purpose.

Comment: So anchor the search at the start of the line with... `grep -w "^$i" sizes.txt`

Comment: Ah...that's what I'm looking for (simply never used that "anchoring" facility).  Thanks Mark, thanks Khanad.

Comment: Edited the post based on the feedback from Mark Setchell

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using only bash built-in functions and syntax:

```
while read -r user ; do
  while read -r s_user s_column_2 s_column_3 s_column_4  ; do
    [ "${s_user}" = "${user}" ] && printf "%b\t%b\t%b\t%b\n" "${s_user}" "${s_column_2}" "${s_column_3}" "${s_column_4}"
  done < sizes.txt
done < users.txt
```

this nested `while` could be slow when using big size.txt files. In those cases you could use this in combination with `awk`